# Href with no value triggering reload on second visit to page

Tags: html, click, href, pageload

We have following link on our page:

```
<a href="" class="link">Link</a>
```

It has a click event bind to it which just toggles a class and returns false. When I am opening the page first time in browser, the click event works fine. But after reloading the page or opening it second time (in other tab or same tab, not in other window), the click of this link is reloading the page.

Adding `href="javascript:void(0)"` fixes the problem but why is this behaving like this on empty `href`?